# proxy won't work in create-react-app and axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, create-react-app

I added `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` in package.json, and I run npm run start to start the client app.

then I do this with axios

```
axios.get('/')
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
      this.setState({
        name: resp.name
      })
    })
```

I open the network tab I'm seeing it calls http://localhost:3000 not the proxy, any clue? I have an express server running on 3001.

Comment: Can't you use `fetch` instead?

Comment: @mersocarlin I can but I want to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> open the network tab I'm seeing it calls http://localhost:3000 not the proxy

That's how proxies work! The browser makes a request to `localhost:3000` where your proxy server is running, which forwards the request to `localhost:3001`

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in webpack config file,with your own starter pack just set "webpack.dev.js" as in code bellow

`module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    open: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        secure: false
      }
    }
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-maps'
});`

and set apropriate localhost for your server and restart dev-server.
      In "create-react-app" webpack config files should be on path `/node_modules/react-scripts/config`,make changes as in code above and restart dev-server and you should be fine.
     On this path are 
`webpack.config.dev.js`. //used by `npm start`
`webpack.config.prod.js` //used by `npm run build`